# Your function's execution role doesn't have permission to send result to the destination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-sns

I want to send message from lambda function to SNS. When I am trying to add destination "SNS" then this error is coming. What  are the IAM Policies, i am missing ? I have added AWSLambdaFullAccess and AmazonSNSFullAccess IAM policies.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not the lambda execution policy, but you (your **IAM user**) does not have permissions to perform `iam:AttachRolePolicy`.

The reason is that the lambda will add the following **service-role policy** to your function execution role, regardless the fact that you already have `AmazonSNSFullAccess` there:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sns:Publish",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:region:xxxx:testTopic"
        }
    ]
}
```

You have to add the missing permissions to the IAM user you use when login to the console.